# Executing direct query in Magento 2 issue

Tags: magento2, query

this is my code:

```
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
$connection->query("SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000");
```

I have a query using a group concat. The return values length is greater that the current group_concat_max_len value that I have set in mysql (1024).

After running that code from a cronjob , I am going to mysql console and execute this query: `SELECT @@group_concat_max_len;` I'm still getting 1024 instead of 1000000. However If execute this query directly in my mysql console: `SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000` the length is updated immediately . Why that query doesn't work from my cronjob ?
Thanks